# could not show items in navbar as per the need

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using reactjs and material-ui for development of my application. I am developing a dashboard. Before i used react-mdl for component and using it the navbar component is working as expected. I want to use material-ui, though as it has lots of component and support. It is mature than react-mdl. Everything is working perfectly except navbar component where i have used AppBar.

Below is the screenshot of navbar i have designed using both material-ui and react-mdl. I want the 2nd navbar(it is designed using react-mdl) using material-ui which i could not. I tried using tab inside AppBar but no luck. The concept is there will be 2 tab at first and when the add icon is clicked that is on the right side, user gets to add a new tab over there. How can i design it the same way?

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
render() {
    const navigation = (
      <BottomNavigation style={{ background:'transparent'}}>
        <i className="material-icons md-23">delete</i>
        <i className="material-icons md-23">add_circle</i>
      </BottomNavigation>
    )

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="mdlContent" style={{height: '900px', position: 'relative'}}>
        <AppBar  iconElementRight={navigation} >
        </AppBar>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via passing a `component` as the title to the `<AppBar/>` component.

Check the following pen:

https://codepen.io/pranesh-r/pen/LROLbo

Instead of using `tabs` inside the `navBar` which is a bit tricky, you can use `<a>` and handle the route to render the specific page.

Comment: This work but i created an array of navigation inside state because user should get to add the tabs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method - put your navigation items into an array in your state.  You can add new items to this array.  Use Tabs in the nav bar to display the items:

```
getInitialState(){
  const navigation = [
   { id: 0, description: "Dashboard"},
   { id: 1, description: "My Device"},
   { id: 2, description: "Follow"}
  ]; 
}

render(){
<div>
  <Tabs onChange={this.handleChange}>
    {this.state.navigation.map( function(result, index){
      return <Tab key={result.id} label={result.description} value={index}/>
    })}        
  </Tabs>
</div>
```

Check out the library swipeableviews: https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views.  You can place the views in the same render function so that each tab has a corresponding view to display the menu content.

```
<div>
  <SwipeableViews>
  ...
  </SwipeableViews
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing knowledge.